# AudioContext.decodeAudioData seems to create crackling noise

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-audio-api

I'm creating a electron app that allows user to cut and rearrange multiple audio samples and seemlessly play them. The total duration of samples can be longer then hour, so I cannot decode them all and store them as pcm data. So here's what I implemented:
 - First decode audio `ArrayBuffers` that are needed to create first piece of `AudioBufferSourceNode`.
 - While playing the first `AudioBufferSourceNode`, create next buffer the same way, and play them right after first buffer ends.

The problem is, audio seems to have a cracking noise once in a while. every buffer plays right after another, and I've applied few miliseconds of decay in start and end of cut audio, so I'm sure It's not from sudden start/stop of audio.
strange thing is, the cracking noise only happens when audio decoding is  running asynchronously. I've implemented this function to store recently decoded pcm, and when playing from cache there were no such cracking noise. Also, when I put a infinite loop of audio decoding running in background, there were clearly more cracks in audio.

I've searched google for this kind of problem, but I couldn't find anyone who had the same problem. So my question is, can `decodeAudioData` really cause cracking noise? And if it is, how can I fix it?

This happens on every computer, but low-performance computer seems to have more cracks.

Here's the code I used to decode, which is a singleton for `AudioContext`.

```js
class AudioDecoder {
  // Number of audioContext of limited,
  // using a singleton to prevent hitting the limit
  private audioCtx: AudioContext;
  private static instance: AudioDecoder;
  private constructor() {
    const AudioContextClass =
      (window as any).AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
    this.audioCtx = new AudioContextClass();
  }
  public static decode = (arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) => {
    if (!AudioDecoder.instance) {
      AudioDecoder.instance = new AudioDecoder();
    }
    return new Promise<AudioBuffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      AudioDecoder.instance.audioCtx.decodeAudioData(
        arrayBuffer,
        buffer => {
          resolve(buffer);
        },
        error => reject(error),
      );
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle `decodeAudioData` shouldn't produce cracking noise unless the original source had it.

**However**, if the sample rate of the compressed audio file differs from the sample rate of the `AudioContext`, the decoded audio is resampled to match the context.  Generally, this isn't noticeable, but you're concatenating buffers for playback, there could be a discontinuity that isn't there in the original.  You should check to see if the sample rate of the audio file differs from the rate of the context. If they're different, retry with an audio file with a sample rate that matches the context.  Or construct the context with the sample rate that matches the file. (Not available on all browsers yet.)

Finally, if this doesn't resolve the problem, file an issue with your browser and be sure to include a short but complete test case.